# Pros and Cons of Sharepoint vs Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, sharepoint

I want to understand the differences in applications developing in Sharepoint and Standalone Silverlight application.  My application is going to be a dashboard kind of application which some charts and graphs with metrical data.

Can anyone summarize Pros and Cons of developing this application in Sharepoint
and Pros and Cons of developoing this application in Silverlight

Comment: Also, which version of SharePoint? There's a huge difference between 2007/WSS3.0 and 2010.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SharePoint will give you control on the data itself. You'll be able to include scenarios involving workflows (e.g. approval) or where access is restricted. For example I worked on a project where the customer had two vendors, and of course he didn't want vendor two to see vendor one 's data on the dashboard.

SharePoint will also give you more rendering options, either html or Silverlight. This will be useful if you need to support a wide range of devices (including mobile).

The cons are the overhead involved with the SharePoint deployment.

As John Saunders said, it is a broad topic and there is no simple answer. One important factor to consider is the size of your project. If you are in a corporate environment involving collaboration, most likely SharePoint will be a good option, either with or without Silverlight.

Answer (score 1):

Presumptions-

- You are *required* to involve SharePoint in some way (intranet? managers use SharePoint?)!

### SharePoint

#### Pros

- Direct access to SharePoint data and objects
- Easily added to SharePoint sites/pages etc

#### Cons

- Stuck within the SharePoint platform
- More involved to get the development environment going (maybe you already have this setup)
- It's SharePoint

### SilverLight

#### Pros

- Can be viewed in any browser with the SilverLight plugin
- Can itself be displayed within SharePoint (e.g. appears to be in SharePoint)
- Not tied to SharePoint

#### Cons

- Requires the SilverLight plugin to be installed on each client's machine as well as the correct version etc
- May need to access SharePoint web services rather than having direct access to SharePoint (If your dashboard data comes from sharepoint)
- A separate server (or the same) to host any WebServices that it might require

**Edit**
It's possibly worth you mentioning what control sets you have access to as if you have licenses to either SharePoint or SilverLight third party controls this might effect what the result of your Dashboards are

Feel free to add to this...

Comment: Much of your answer depends on the version of Sharepoint

Comment: @JohnSaunders very true. I haven't seen 2010 but hopefully it's improved.

Comment: The development picture is radically different. Best example: you don't have to develop on a server anymore, and SharePoint development is built in to Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint and Silverlight are able to access the Data directly. Think about

- ClientObject Model / Server Side Object Model
- REST Service
- SharePoint WebServices

Building dashboards in SharePoint (by using WebParts) are OOB configurable for the user. The users already know how to use SharePoint because of it's consistent UserInterface.

The advantage of Silverlight will be that you dashboard could be installed on the desktop if you're adding OutOfBrowser support.

I think Silverlight has some disadvantages, but they really depend on your requirements and on your target audience

- Reach (on the internet only a few percent have installed Silverlight plugin)
- Security (based on SharePoint there is already a security model)

SharePoint is offering a lot of platform features which will cost a lot of money to reinvent them in Silverlight.

Just my cents ;)

Thorsten