# Building a web application within .Net framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, silverlight, sharepoint

I have to do a web application with the framework .Net. I find three ways to build this application:

1. [*Sharepoint*](http://office.microsoft.com/fr-fr/sharepoint/)
2. [*Silverlight*](http://www.microsoft.com/silverlight/)
3. [*Asp .Net*](http://www.asp.net/)

I need to make a decision and choose one of them . So i'd like to know

1. What are the big differences between them?
2. In which cases, i have to choose one not the others?
3. Can we make a comparison between them on several criterias(flexibility, maintenability...)?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's hard to recommend one over the other without knowing what your application is.

Choosing Technology choice can be judged by many parameters as below,

·         User Experience
·         Infrastructure
·         Security
·         Performance
·         Architecture
·         People
·         Strategic
·         Cost
·         License

**SilverLight**

One thing you have to understand 1st and foremost is that Silverlight requires the client to download a small Plugin (just like Flash does as well) to enable all that rich-client capability and the ability to run managed code on the client. If you are in an environment where either distribution or downloading of the plugin is not possible then Silverlight is out as an option.

**ASP.Net**

ASP.NET on the other hand is the old trusty web platform that has been around since .NET 1.0. And now with the option between web forms and ASP.NET MVC you have many Architectural options available for building your ASP.NET app. Combine technologies like WCF into the mix, and you have serious potential for writing and creating Enterprise Applications.

If you want or need the rich UI abilities of Silverlight, then make a few controls and add them to your ASP.NET pages to give you the best of both technologies without being too heavily invested in Silverlight.

**My Recommendation**
If I was in your position I would probably go with an ASP.NET application (webforms or MVC is your choice.).
I say this not because ASP.NET is superior and Silverlight can't make Enterprise Apps , but because it is the safer and more reliable choice I think given what our future looks like in .NET.

Comment: Thank you , but what about Sharepoint?

Comment: @Lamloumi I haven't used sharepoint much to comment about it.

Comment: @Lamloumi you can check the following [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8844802/pros-and-cons-of-sharepoint-vs-silverlight)

Answer (score 0):

I can comment largely on the general http/javascript vs. Silverlight decision, as I have no experience developing in Sharepoint.

#### Browser compatibility

Html/javascript used to be notorious for incompatibilities, and although this has improved a lot, Silverlight is still better in that area.

The plugin behaves mostly the same in all browsers. I use Chrome myself and my customers usually use Internet Explorer, some Firefox. In the last few years I had not one problem due to a browser incompatibility - and I know how much web developers used to fight with those. This is probably one of the main strengths, *if* Silverlight runs on a platform, it runs the same as on all others.

There is one subtle and not well-known caveat (bug) though, but it's not depending on the browser. There is a certain kind of memory leak that can occur on tablet devices, see this stackoverflow answer. It's the only time I experienced a Silverlight application to be dependent on an environmental factor.

#### Operating system compatibility

This is a major point for html/javascript, as all major browsers are ported to all major operating systems and platforms.

Obviously you are going to run Windows-only with Silverlight. There is a mac implementation, but you should test early because there Silverlight might actually *do* behave differently in many cases. I can't say much to how serious that implementation actually is.

Much more disappointing is Microsoft's policy on their own platform: The WinRT tablet (the non-professional, ARM-based one) doesn't support Silverlight, and of course the metro-IE doesn't either (infamously).

In a nutshell, Silverlight is still a viable option in cases where you target a corporate environment where you can estimate the hardware your customers will have, as well as in those cases where there are few technical alternatives - such as when you need a good adaptive video streaming technology.

#### Third party designs

One thing where html-based solutions can shine is design: Although I love Expression Blend, my love doesn't seem to be shared by most web designers. The amount of html/css templates you can find for html, even for line-of-business applications, is amazing. For Silverlight (and WPF), there is almost nothing at all. In fact I don't know a single beautiful design for Silverlight that hasn't been created by Microsoft themselves - and they too have created ugly ones as well.

As someone who loves Silverlight - the ability to just pick and buy a really beautiful theme for my next app is probably the thing I'm most envious of when I'm looking at the html world, much more so even than platform support.

Today I'd suggest html as a default unless the one of the following points apply:

- You are already familiar with Silverlight (or your team is).
- You need to do complex rich-text editing capabilities that go beyond an html editor.
- You need to access COM interfaces or do P/Invoke on Windows (although you can also supplement a html/javascript client with Silverlight for that)
- You want to provide the ability to "install" an application (out-of-browser mode).
- You have complex business logic that you want to execute on the server and the client alike, and you want to write that in C# rather than Javascript.

If any of these things hold, Silverlight might be an option (as well as WPF).